# same results for php if inside foreach

Tags: php

My problem is that as soon as my php variable was used for the first time, the same value shows up in every loop, though it is uncorrect:

```
$json_matches=file_get_contents('url');
$matches = json_decode($json_matches,true);

//json results
foreach($matches as $object)

//filter results
if ($object['season'] == $season && $object['localteam_id'] == $hteam) {

    //add up localteam and visitorteam goals
    $goals_match=$object['localteam_score']+$object['visitorteam_score'];

        //check if result is larger than 4 and save value to variable
        if($goals_match > 4) $goals_p4=1;

    echo $object['id']." ". $goals_p4;

    }
```

As soon as I have a correct result for `$goals_match > 4` the `1` shows up correctly. But in my next results no matter if wrong or right, the `1` appears again and again.

I have checked several posts in here, but have not found any tips to solve this problem. Would be great if you could help me here!

Thank you very much!

Comment: instead of `$goals_p4=1;`  directly use `echo '1';`. Also can you show this full code because your code is not full

Comment: That works, but I need the `1` in a variable to calculate. That would not be possible then, right?

Comment: first can you please add brackets so that it will remove ambiguity. i am unable to understand where foreach ended and where first if condition is ended

Comment: Sorry, hope the clean up helps a little.

Comment: check my answer once

Comment: vloryan i think i am the first person who gave you the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because you're not resetting or re-initialising the `$goals_p4` variable once it has been used, as such it is keeping the value.

One way of fixing this would be the following, but you don't state what a default value for $goals_p4 should be, or if the value should be stored somewhere:

```
$json_matches=file_get_contents('url');
$matches = json_decode($json_matches,true);

//json results
foreach($matches as $object)
{
  //filter results
  if ($object['season'] == $season && $object['localteam_id'] == $hteam) 
  {
    $goals_p4 = ''; // reset to it is blank for each loop

    //add up localteam and visitorteam goals
    $goals_match=$object['localteam_score']+$object['visitorteam_score'];

    //check if result is larger than 4 and save value to variable
    if($goals_match > 4) 
    {
      $goals_p4=1; // will only be set to 1 if the $goals_match is over 4, if not it will remain default
    }

    echo $object['id']." ". $goals_p4;  // $goals_p4 will either be 1 or blank

  }    

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That helped!

Comment: It's possibly worth noting that if you develop with notice warnings turned on, if you run the original code through it with information which would gave `$goals_match` <= 4, then you'd get a warning about an undefined variable, based on the code you posted.  It would only become defined once it has been initialised to something.